# make drive show up as fixed rather than "removable"?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, removable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP, USB-Stick and multiple Partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/windows-xp-usb-stick-and-multiple-partitions)

Is there a way to make a usb drive show up as a fixed drive and not a removable drive?

Comment: you mean, besides removing the drive from the USB enclosure and plugging it directly into the computer's SATA/IDE bus?

Comment: yes i mean make the USB drive show up as fixed and not removable

Comment: Possible duplicate with my own question: http://superuser.com/questions/61487/windows-xp-usb-stick-and-multiple-partitions

Answer (score 0):

On flash drive only the first partition works

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html#partitioning