# Sync folders with Skydrive on Windows RT, ideally on MicroSD

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I have all my music synced with Skydrive. On my Windows 8 laptop I included Skydrive Music folder into the Music library, so all my music is accessible with Media Player or Xbox Music app. Apparently I can even [sync my Skydrive data with MicroSD card](https://superuser.com/questions/469410/how-could-i-let-skydrive-desktop-sync-to-microsd-in-windows-8-tablet).

How can I do the same thing on Windows RT? Desktop Skydrive application does not run on Windows RT and it seems like "Metro style" Skydrive app allows only to upload files and only one by one.

Comment: Is there not a Skydrive app you can download? Also, can you access explorer?

Comment: @cable729: I can access explorer, but Skydrive is not built in. There is a Skydrive app, but it seems it works only with files. I can upload/download a file, but I don't see a how I can sync a folder with Skydrive app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows RT it is currently not possible to sync your SkyDrive content. I think it is quite well explained here:

> Note that because Windows RT is incompatible with externally installed
>   Windows desktop applications, the SkyDrive desktop application is not
>   available for Windows RT devices like the Surface with Windows RT.
>   This means that you can only access your SkyDrive contents through the
>   Metro-style app, which is bundled with RT. And that makes sense:
>   Windows RT is a new mobile operating system, not a hybrid OS like
>   Windows 8, which includes both mobile and desktop components.

Source: [Windows 8 Tip: Understand The Differences Between The SkyDrive App And The SkyDrive Application](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-understand-differences-skydrive-app-skydrive-application-144573)

Comment: I was hoping there would still be a way to do it, at least just to download all files from skydrive in one shot instead of doing it one by one...

Comment: Well there is a way to download a folder in one shot by going to http://www.skydrive.com, login and select a folder and click "Download" (at the top or from the context menu by right clicking on a folder). I am not sure if this works for large folders, but maybe you could try it. However this will download the files to your tablet, it of course is not the same as syncing a folder.

Comment: Tried it, it downloads all files as zip archive. At least it is better than nothing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I still need to investigate, but it seems that Windows 8.1 has this Skydrive sync behavior built in. It seems that just having the Skydrive 'Metro' app installed (and the Skydrive desktop sync app not running) syncs Skydrive content on my Windows 8.1 Pro tablet. There is also an option for folders/files on Skydrive to be "only online available" or "also offline availble" with a context menu to change this. This might be what you are looking for?