# 4GB USB as 2 drives

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, fat32, google-chrome-os

I've got a 4GB USB flash drive and am trying to partition it.  I'd like 2GB to be an OS (ChromeOS by Hexxeh), and the rest should be one FAT32 partition.

- Windows should recognize the FAT32 partition.
- My BIOS should recognize the other as bootable.

Windows partition manager seems to allow you to make a partition if a partition already exists.  Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: define "seems not to like to do this". What part fails?

Comment: Thanks Draemon, I edited the question to be more precise

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/61487/windows-xp-usb-stick-and-multiple-partitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a tutorial, you may find helpful:

**[Multi Partition a USB Flash Drive in Windows](http://www.lancelhoff.com/multi-partition-a-usb-flash-drive-in-windows/)**

Comment: This is the way to do it. +1

Comment: Once you've done this, how do you "eject" the drive to make sure all the data has been written to the drive before you remove it? I'm assuming without the removable bit set the drive will not offer the option to eject the media.

Comment: Is this true to all flash drives?Because I tried it  on my 8gb toshiba and it doesnt work. What would be the recommended size of usb?

Comment: @user23950  - "This tool may not work on all flash drives" ... happens.

Comment: Anyone know of a tool that'll flip the removable bit on a SanDisk Cruzer?  The Lexar BootIt app doesn't work.

Comment: @AMWJ - flipping the Removable Media Bit on the device descriptor of a SanDisk Cruzer is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The fat32 partition must be the **first** partition on the device or windows will not mount it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to try this application. It's free:

http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

> Support Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Windows7 (32 bit & 64 bit) operating system.
>
> Support RAID.
>
> Extend system partition to maximize computer performance.
>
> Manage the hard disk for substantial performance increase.
>
> Create , Delete and Format partitions with simple steps.
>
> Disk Copy to protect or transfer data.
>
> Support disk and partition size larger than 2 TB.
>
> Convert partition format from FAT to NTFS.
>
> Partition Copy: Copy the entire content of one hard disk to another.
>
> Copy Disk Wizard: Copy the entire hard disk to another without having to reinstall Windows.
>
> Disk Map - Visually demonstrate your disk/partition configuration; preview the changes before applying. Hide/unhide partition, set active partition, etc. -
>
> Change partition properties easily.
>
> Explore FAT/NTFS partition.
>
> Set partition as primary.
>
> Set partition as logical.

Comment: -1, I can't at least get this to see my USB Thumb drive (8GB Patriot XT

Comment: And you downvote for that???

Comment: I also see no indication on the website that it works with a USB flash drive, didn't work with my big flash drive or the two generic ones on my desk either. You gave a bad answer, so yes that is a downvote kid-o

Comment: It doesn't recognize my USB.