# Can I fool Windows XP into thinking my USB stick is a fixed disk?

Tags: windows, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP, USB-Stick and multiple Partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/windows-xp-usb-stick-and-multiple-partitions)

I want to make Windows think that my USB drive is a fixed local drive. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you just want to make sure the USB drive has a permanent drive letter?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible on some disks. Basically, there a setting in drive's firmware which windows uses to detect if it's fixed or mobile. Here's a program which is supposed to be able to change the setting:
http://www.getusb.info/flip-your-bit-usb-utility-to-make-local-drive/
Program is Lexar's Bootit and it's reported to work on other flash drives.

Answer (score 0):

Read [**here**](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbstick_e.html) the 4th paragraph.

> Nearly all USB flash drives pretend to have a removable media (even it's a lie), so Windows detects them as 'removable'. On drives with a removable media Windows 2000 and higher supports only one partition.
>   Finally it's a single bit in the device's device descriptor, the removable media bit (RMB). If you take away the RMB then Windows sees the drive as 'local disk' and multiple partitions work.
>
> The Removable Media Bit can be changed either in the drive's hardware or by a Windows filter driver.
>   Changing in the hardware works with some flash drives by means of the tool [Lexar BootIt](http://rapidshare.com/files/243375388/lexar_usb_format.zip).

Comment: What happens when that site is down/offline/gone?

Comment: Well.. the planet will be doomed.

I can't copy the answer, cause there is a table form over there.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.