# How to Modify Windows 7 Search to Index Removable Drives

Tags: windows-7, search, usb-flash-drive

I have over 8GB in my "Code Library" that I maintain on a 64GB "ScanDisk Ultra Backup USB Device".

Windows Search 4.0 (installed on Windows XP) can index removable drives, but Windows 7 (which uses Windows Search 4.0) cannot because the USB device identifies itself as a "Removable" drive and Windows 7 refuses to index removable drives.

How can I modify Windows 7 Search to index removable drives?

All suggestions welcome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Mount a USB "Thumb" Drive as "Fixed" in Windows (For Indexing)](http://superuser.com/questions/248639/how-to-mount-a-usb-thumb-drive-as-fixed-in-windows-for-indexing)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. In one case I am trying to "fool" Windows  to index removable drives by making those drives appear as fixed. In this case, I am trying to get Windows 7 to search removable drives. I know it case because Windows Search 4 can.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by [mounting the drive as an NTFS folder rather than by drive letter](http://lifehacker.com/5788839/how-to-add-unsupported-removable-drives-to-windows-7s-libraries). This would let you add it as a library.

Comment: Please add the essential information from the linked article to your reply. This link can stop functioning the same way.

Comment: You need to include the information contained in the link you posted in your answer. Not the whole thing, but enough to show the steps taken to address the issue, this is to prevent link rot.

Comment: The link in the other answer is working. No need for this answer.