# Flipping the Removable Media bit -- alternatives to BootIt?

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

There's a utility called the Lexar BootIt utility that flips the Removable Media Bit on certain USB flash drives.

I want to flip the bit on my USB flash drive (it's supported) but really am not too comfortable downloading this utility from random file-sharing sites, nor do I see a license anywhere for it.

The end goal is to recommend a tool for corporate customers so they may flip the bits themselves.

Are there any free or open alternatives to this tool?

Comment: it doesn't work on all systems so this is a good question about alternatives to BootIt

Comment: Hitachi Filter Driver is not eligible for an answer :)

Comment: i have no idea why they closed this question, these mods probably have too much time on their hands. anyways, there's a couple of great usb drivers that can do the job for you if you set them as the drivers for the specific device http://agnipulse.com/2012/03/filter-drivers-removable-media-fixed-disk-windows/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why would you want to flip the removable bit on your USB Drive?
Which USB Drive do you have?

If you want to partition your USB Flash Drive then you can use Bootice
http://agnipulse.com/2011/11/partition-usb-flash-drive/

If you really want to flip the removable bit then you have use Mass Production tools to reprogram the microcontroller in your USB Flash Drive. However this procedure varies for all USB Flash Drives. Most Mass Production tools are used to repair USB Flash Drives or to add or remove CDFS Partition; However, some MP Tools provide the option to Flip the Removable bit.

The general procedure to reprogram your USB Flash Drive to Flip the bit or make other changes is as follows:

Download and Run Chipgenius and find out the VID and PID of your USB Drive.
http://agnipulse.com/2010/03/chipgenius-and-usbdeview-usb-information-tools/
Edit: [(Archived download of chipgenius)](http://web.archive.org/web/20180818143614/http://www.mydigit.cn/mytool/chipgenius.rar), [(Alternatively use Nirsoft's USBDeview to get the drive's VID and PID)](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)

Go to http://flashboot.ru/iflash.html and enter the VID and PID of your USB Drive.Check if there are any MassProduction tools available and download them. Then you will have to figure how to use it.

Check this for detailed guide on how to do this.(In this guide the MPtool is being used to repair a fake USB Drive)
http://agnipulse.com/2010/04/how-i-fixed-a-fake-64gb-usb-drive/

**Warning** - The procedure varies for different USB Flash Drives and you may end up with irreparable USB Flash Drive.

Note:

I have tried flipping the bit of Transcend Jetflash USB Drives with good success. The MPtool for JetFlash USB Drives is called AlcorMptool and this MpTool has the option to flip the removable bit.
Another reason why I feel comfortable to use JetFlash USB Drives is because it can be fixed easily if something goes wrong.

http://agnipulse.com/2010/04/jetflash-online-recovery-repair-your-transcend-usb-drives-for-free/

Comment: I ended up using this approach (mass production tools) before you posted it and it worked on some of our flash drives.  Thanks for summarizing it so nicely!

Comment: I am glad that this method worked for some of your flash drives.Can you please post the list of pen drives(manufacturer or model name) that worked for you? Also can you please tell us why you want to flip the removable bit?

Comment: The drive it worked on was already listed in the flashboot.ru site.  Wanted to flip the RMB to boot a full version of Windows off of it.

Comment: Interesting.How does flipping the RMB help in booting a full version of Windows from USB Drive?I have been able to boot a full version of Windows from both a USB Flash drive and a USB Hard Disk.I have answered your other question.http://superuser.com/questions/392493/is-it-possible-to-create-a-full-windows-7-live-dvd/394098#394098

Comment: Thanks @bbalegere.  I'll need to check it out.  It's a big hassle to mess with the RMB -- would love to skip that step.

Comment: You ask: "Why would you want to flip the removable bit of a flash drive?" at the top. Well, one might simply want to fool windows into making a SYSTEM IMAGE of a fresh install of a laptop on nice small thumb drive that fits right in a safety deposit box.... But, NO, Microsoft's built in backup DOES NOT LIKE like saving a system image to a thumb drive. I guess I could always just boot Linux... thanks Microsoft! (they love plugging Linus, this question proves it :-D).

Comment: @RyanWoodard Use [`Dism /Capture-Image`](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) from WinPE/WinRE to save an image to a USB drive - this is far more efficient than GUI options.

Comment: @bbalegere There are certain instances where the removable bit must be flipped in order to accomplish certain tasks - for example, Windows doesn't allow offlining a flash drive, which is problematic when wanting to mount a flash drive on a VM in Hyper-V _(there are additional scenarios, and until Microsoft changes this hardcoded programming, flipping a bit will be necessary in certain circumstances)_.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to download a utility from a website that you don't know, how about compiling your own.

See the codeproject.com article [Hooking the kernel directly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13677/Hooking-the-kernel-directly) by Anton Bassov,
containing the sources for a USB filter driver.

I would suggest reading very carefully the entire article and all comments.

The article dates from 2006. It looks like it may still pertain to the latest Windows versions,
but I cannot guarantee this.

Anton Bassov himself seems to be available [on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=16075700&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=PE8u&locale=en_US&srchid=63ab8b56-9e38-4dfa-98ec-0f3149291365-0&srchindex=1&srchtotal=2&goback=.fps_PBCK_*1_Anton_Bassov_*1_*1_*1_*1_*2_*1_Y_*1_*1_*1_false_1_R_*1_*51_*1_*51_true_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&pvs=ps&trk=pp_profile_name_link) (I haven't tried to contact him).

Comment: There's the source for the Hitachi Filter Driver floating around too