# Multipart pendrive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can I create and access more partitions in a pendrive in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for me in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/391176/flipping-the-removable-media-bit-alternatives-to-bootit)! A small application that alternates the first partition without having to reboot.

Long story short, you download and run [Bootice](http://bbs.ipauly.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2), go "Parts Manage" > select your new first partition in the table > click "Set Accessible" and it's done already! After that you can just click close and exit.

Comment: This saved my life you have no idea! Trevor Trovalds you rock so effing hard today

Answer (score 1):

Insert a flash drive, open a run dialog, type in "diskmgmt.msc", and you will be able to split the partitions of the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [forum post](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1655684) which appears to point to a 64-bit compiled driver. I think this is what you're looking for. Please, take appropriate caution when downloading random files *et cetera*.

For the record, my Google search term was: `removable drive bit x64`, and that showed up near the top.

Comment: Unfortunate. That hack is insane! Replacing registry hives with the defaults during system recovery. I will make a note of that.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows disk management as suggested above doesn't work then try http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm
its free but upon installation **avoid installing crapware!** (read the prompts carefully)
I usually multi-partition my usb drives under linux w/ cfdisk, afterwards they work under MAC & Lin but my 4 partition beast has problems under Windows XP :(