# USB making tool for Windows detects flash drive as fixed, need to be seen as removable

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

I downloaded the Windows 8.1 ISO file but my laptop doesn't have an optical drive. The only choice is to install it from USB. I found a Windows 7 USB making tool (the some works for Windows 8 as I found from Microsoft site).

No issues until now. When I run the tool it can't find my flash drive (SanDisk Cruzer Blade of 16GB) and upon lots of debugging I found that the USB drive is detected as static (fixed) drive. The tool won't recognize any static ones.

Can I make my SanDisk USB drive to be detected as removable?

Comment: You do know that Windows 8.1 has the ability to reset your installation which will set your system into what basically is a fresh installation state right?  Since you have a Windows 8.1 license you should be able to use the Windows 8.1 on the Microsoft website to download create the bootable usb.

Comment: I always prefer Rufus: http://rufus.akeo.ie/ Look if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Answer here [Flipping the Removable Media bit -- alternatives to BootIt?](https://superuser.com/questions/391176/flipping-the-removable-media-bit-alternatives-to-bootit)

You might want to reprogram your USB Drive by using Mass Production to flip the removable bit.

Alternatively - you can install filter drivers to disguise your USB drive as Removable or Fixed.

http://agnipulse.com/2012/03/filter-drivers-removable-media-fixed-disk-windows/

Comment: There is no such program as "Mass Production." The other thread is referring to "mass production" as in the software used by the manufacturer in the factory.