# What is the difference in writing data to an external HDD compared to a USB flash drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have a Humax satellite receiver with the ability to record programmes (with an external storage connected via a USB slot). What was surprising when I read the manual is it said that only USB hard drives can be used and USB flash drives will not work.

Although it is able to read the contents of flash drives and view any media they contain, it will not write, why is that? What is the hardware/software difference in writing to these different devices?

Comment: Likely drivers.  Without knowing the specific implementation of the USB stack it's hard to know.  It likely is also an artificial limitation

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound that it's probably an artificial limitation. Does the receiver require a blank drive for this feature? If not, it could be a filesystem thing. An external hard drive is likely formatted with NTFS while most flash drives are FAT32 and hence have a 4GB file limit which may be prohibitive for programme recording. Have you tried an NTFS formatted flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

Flash drives have a "removable bit" that differentiates them from USB hard drives. Here is a [more detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/393842/216298).

Answer (score -1):

I have a DiVx player connected to TV, bur the thing is oposite. I can watch movies only from USB stick but not from external HDD. It is all about fs.