# Is there a way to make a USB drive to work like internal storage?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

So I have this USB thumb drive of 16GB, which when inserted into my laptop gets assigned a drive letter (eg. E:/ or F:/), whereas when I connect my smartphone to my laptop usb, it just shows internal storage.

Is there a way to format my USB thumb drive so that it appears as 'Internal Storage' and not as a separate drive. Tried googling but got no solution, maybe I am not using the right keywords.

Edit: OS Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: You can do this by flipping the removable bit. http://superuser.com/questions/391176/flipping-the-removable-media-bit-alternatives-to-bootit

Comment: Try Ready Boost ==> https://www.winhelp.us/use-readyboost-in-windows-vista-and-7.html

Comment: What's the benefit to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like confusion between MTP, or the Media Transfer Protocol on the smartphone and USB Mass Storage as seen on your USB thumb drives.

I do not think that you can change USB thumb drives to MTP mode. You can change them to be considered "Hard Disk Drives" rather than "Drives with Removable Storage" if you flip the removable bit, but YMMV. On some drives the bit can be flipped, on others it cant - it just depends on the brand/model/OEM/etc.