# Flip the Removable Bit of a USB Drive

Tags: virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive, usb-3, removable-media

So, I want to use my USB drive on a windows 10 guest virtual machine running on a windows 11 dev channel host. I'm using Hyper-V as the virtual machine manager, and to access the drive on the guest system, I need to be able to offline the disk. I have tried just routing it through, but this doesn't allow the device to be viewed as a drive, but rather as a folder located at `\\tsclient\G`. Using the `subst` command in PowerShell allows be to cd to the device as a drive letter, but the windows explorer `Windows can't find 'z:/'` . I have tried installing VirtualBox, which allows you to directly mount the USB to the VM without offlining the disk, but it fails to install. I have also tried using the old Lexar BootIt tool, but that fails to work either. Is there any way that still works to flip the removable bit, or edit the registry to make offlining a removable drive possible, or is it just another problem lost to time.

[Guest Machine](https://www.wevideo.com/view/2596011116)

[VirtualBox Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpLW1.png)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/391176/flipping-the-removable-media-bit-alternatives-to-bootit

Comment: I saw this, but my antivirus flagged Chipgenius as malware

Comment: It says " (Alternatively use Nirsoft's USBDeview to get the drive's VID and PID)"

Comment: If there are no MP tools for my usb do you have another Idea?

Comment: Using a different USB flash drive?

Comment: oh well, hank then

Comment: Does it have to be a USB flash drive? Or would a/another virtual hard drive also be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing.  One single bit can cause so much frustration.

Apparently there is a alternative USB driver, but it's unsigned, [Removable USB Flash Drive as Local HDD in Windows 10 / 7](http://woshub.com/removable-usb-flash-drive-as-local-disk-in-windows-7/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yep, I ended up finding this, and it worked for what I needed, though I do caution you, everytime I turned on the computer with it installed, it would fail to boot, and I would have to go through the advanced boot section to "disable driver signing", so I recommend swapping it back to the default driver once you are done, as it can be a pain when you just want to turn on your computer. Thanks though!