# Mount a Second Partition of a USB Drive on Windows

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, mount

I have a Pen-drive of 8GB, I have 2 partitions on it, one of 15MB and another of the remaining (7GB+).

I know that Windows only recognizes the first partition, is there any way to mount the second partition on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Management utility, invokable by running diskmgmt.msc?

Comment: Yes, That Does not Help out.

Comment: When the accepted answer IS the other question, yea, I think that qualifies as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a registry hack available for windows. Try the following post.

[USB-Sticks and multiple Partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/usb-sticks-and-multiple-partitions)

Comment: This work only with 32-bits windows...

Answer (score -2):

You just need to activate the primary partition on both partition.

You can follow this command line:

```
diskpart
  list disk
  select <disk number>
  clean
   create partition primary size=2000  (mount of size you want on the usb)
  format quick fs=fat32 label="name it the way you want"
  assign letter=P
  active
```

Comment: What about 4Tb hard disk partitioned with ɢᴘᴛ ?