# Reinitialize USB pendrive that was used to boot linux

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, disk-image

I have a pendrive that was used to boot a linux image (created using `dd if=... of=/dev/sd4 bs =1m` on a mac)

Now I would like to use it again as regular pendrive. Unfortunately I just have a windows xp pc available.
The problem is the drive is 8BG in size - but I can only access about 2GB that were used by the boot image.

In `Computer Management`>`Storage`>`Disk Management` the drive is show 7.45GB in size with a 2.36GB partition. But for the small partition "delete partion" is grayed out, also in the unused space "new partition" is grayed out.

Here's what I tried:

- If I use `diskpart` on the command line `list disk` only shows the built in drives - so I can not select the drive.
- I also tried a 'lexar_usb_format' utility - but it also just allowed me to format the 2.3GB.
- I tried the same on a second XP machine with same results.

If I wait till weekend I can try to restore it on a Mac - but I find it hard to believe there's no way to fix it using plain windows.

(and unfortunately this time I can't boot into linux as the distro won't boot on this PC - bad luck)

Comment: Have you tried formatting the partition? If that works, it would rule out any hardware damage to the USB drive.

Comment: Yes formatting and writing to it works as expected. It's just that the formatted partition is 2.3GB instead of 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `DISKPART` in Windows?

1. Open the Command Prompt as the Administrator, and type `DISKPART`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Type `LIST DISK` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the physical disks attached. Look for which disk is your flash drive (usually `DISK 1` or `DISK 2`).
3. Type `SELECT DISK x` (replace `x` with the number of your flash drive), then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Finally, type `CLEAN` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Type `CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY`, and `ASSIGN LETTER X:` (replace `x:` with any free drive letter).
6. You can also run a `FORMAT` from this program, or run it separately.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. "Unfortunately" I managed to solve this in the mean time on a mac, so I can't try it right now. I just fear it will have the same issue as the disk management tool.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problems is that your pen drive currently has a file system designed for optical disc media (usually [ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)), which does not allow the creation  or deletion of partitions.

Normally, it would suffice to create a new partition table (e.g., an [MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table). Unfortunately, there seems to be no option for this in *Disk Management*.

The easiest way to fix this should be using a third-party partition manager. Most items from [List of disk partitioning software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software) should be able to achieve this.

You could, e.g., download a [GParted LiveCD image](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) and do the following:

1. Burn the image to an optical disc or a pen drive (**not** the drive you're going to format) and boot from it.
2. Select the pen drive by clicking **GParted → Devices → /dev/sdX (7.45 GiB)**.
3. Create a new partition table by clicking **Device → Create Partition Table → Apply**.
4. Create a new partition by clicking **Device → New**, selecting a suitable **File system**<sup>1</sup> and clicking **Add**.
5. Confirm the changes by clicking **Edit → Apply All Operations**.
6. Eject the LiveCD and reboot.

---

<sup>1</sup> Option *fat32* is the safest bet when using both Windows and Mac OS X. Option *ntfs* allows creating files larger than 4 GiB, but Mac OS X cannot write to NTFS partitions without additional software.

Comment: Well I'm already aware that I can fix the problem under a "proper" OS. It's more that I would be interested how to solve it under windows as this had happened to me several times - and rebooting is quite the hassle.

Comment: Actually I think your diagnosis is flawed. As you can see from the discussion I was able to format it to FAT32 (NTFS was also available) and was able to write to it. Neither the "original" image nor ISO 9660 would allow that.

Comment: ad 1. I've posted a tutorial for GParted since that's what I have installed. Most items from [List of disk partitioning software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software) should be able to achieve this. ad 2. Disk Management somehow manages to create a partition without creating a fully functional partition table. Creating a new partition table will allow you to create, modify and delete partitions in Disk Management.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to this "removable bit" mentioned here: [USB sticks and multiple partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/usb-sticks-and-multiple-partitions)

**Edit** The lexar download has moved - but I could find it [here](http://www.getusb.info/flip-your-bit-usb-utility-to-make-local-drive/).
Unfortunately it won't modify my drive. Suppose I would need to make the steps suggested in https://superuser.com/a/471197/98182

Answer (score 0):

I used HPUSBDisk
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool.shtml

Worked for me.