# Partition USB disk for a live cd + data readable on any computer?

Tags: usb, partitioning, livecd

I have a 16Gb USB key that I'd like to make it that way :

- A partition that would contain knoppix and be bootable by any computer (linux, windows based computer)
- A data partition which would be readable by any computer (linux and windows). (probably NTFS)

Problem is, from what I understood, Windows (at least XP) doesn't support multiple partitionned USB keys.

So at first I thought about setting data on the first partition and the live cd on a second partition, but I'm not sure it will work in the bios.

An other solution would be to set the live cd on the first partition and make it hidden resulting windows to not see it, maybe ?

So I'm lost, is there a way to do it like I want ? How ?

Thank you for precious help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its certainly achievable. Perhaps this answer would be useful in this instance.
[USB sticks and multiple partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/usb-sticks-and-multiple-partitions)

Alternatively, make the USB stick one partition and format it in something like Fat32 and haven knoppix and all your storage in one place

http://ftp.knoppix.net/wiki/Category:Hard_drive_Installation