# Create a bootable USB live stick that is still useable on Windows?

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, arch-linux

I would like to format a USB stick (32 GB) in a way so I have:

1. A working *nix live system (preferably [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)), about 3-5 GB in size
2. A 'data' partition that is seen by windows (preferably NTFS) that I can use like any regular USB drive and uses the remaining size of the stick.
3. I want that NTFS partition to be mounted in the Arch Linux live system

I have so far read that the big data partition should be the first in order for Windows to easily work with it. However I think that conflicts with the stick being bootable. Is this still doable?

The stick is a Kingston DataTraveler DTSE9 which I keep on my key ring. The live system is meant as an emergency / recovery system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB-Sticks and multiple Partitions](http://superuser.com/questions/61487/usb-sticks-and-multiple-partitions)

Comment: @techie007 I read that thread, but they are solving the problem by flipping the removable bit, I would like a solution where this isn't necessary by having the NTFS partition as the first one on the stick.

Comment: Keep in mind that windows will only see the first partition on a USB stick. If windows can't understand that partition, it will see the drive as empty and will suggest to format it.

Comment: @LPChip I know that, but is it possible to have a boot partition that is not the first partition?

Answer (score 0):

If FAT32 is acceptable you'll be able to do this with [UNetbootin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin).

Comment: I know I can easily install arch linux live using that, but the problem is I want the stick to appear as a normal drive when plugged into a windows machine. Also I would really like a filesystem that supports files larger than 4GB for the data portion, therefore I suggested NTFS.

Comment: With unetbootin the stick still appears as a normal drive when plugged into a windows machine. But that's right it doesnt support NTFS as far as I know.