# Using a memory stick containing multiple Ext2 filesystems in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, filesystems, removable-media, ext2

I have a memory stick which I have formatted to contain two `ext2` partitions on my Ubuntu computer, one 2 GB and one 6 GB. I would like to use them on my Windows 7 computer now.

I am aware of [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) and I have downloaded it, but I can only see one partition in Explorer. (The first, 2 GB one.)

I also have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/61487/usb-sticks-and-multiple-partitions) about multiple partitions on memory sticks in Windows *XP*. In Windows XP memory sticks can only have one partition, but I am not sure if that has changed in Vista or 7. Also, I am sure I have sometime used a memory stick on the same computer that had two partitions (a big one named `PUBLIC` and a small one named `SECURE`, if that makes any difference).

I could try use the method suggested on the page to flip the removable bit, but I'm not very excited about the risk to lose my data.

Is there a way around this, or do I just have to keep using my Ubuntu computer?

**UPDATE.** I checked the Ext2 Manager, and here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I believe the partition in question is the one on DISK 1 that is identified as FAT32X. (I'm quite sure it is `ext2`, though.) I tried opening its properties.

[image: Screenshot]

I then clicked Mount Points. Nothing was on the list, so I clicked Add.

[image: Screenshot]

I first tried with the default option (in the picture). Clicking OK didn't add anything to the list, so I tried with the first option (via DefineDosDevice). This added `H:` to the list, so I clicked Done. Now `H:` is not being added to the Mount Points textbox (still looks like screenshot 2).

Clicking Exit now put `H:` next to the drive in the list, but it's still not working.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why not copy the files off of the memory stick, format it with NTFS, copy the files back on? Ubuntu supports reading/writing to a NTFS partition.

Comment: The smaller partition is bootable, and I'm not sure all BIOSes work with NTFS.

Comment: Just noticed this question is still open.  Did you get it working?

Comment: @fixer1234 Seems like I kinda forgot about this. Updating question.

Comment: @fixer1234 Okay, added a lot of pictures.

Comment: Quick thought on the automatic mounting--it is triggered by changes.  If the memory stick was already in place and then you set that, it won't detect the stick.  You would need to insert it after the setting.  If you can't get an answer here, you might have more luck on the Linux or Ubuntu sites.

Comment: The partition labelled as FAT32 is FAT32 and the one labelled ext3 is ext3 (it doesn't make mistakes about that).  Whatever you did to format two partitions as ext2 didn't work.  Ext3 is fine.  But I would rerun the partitioning program and do another pass on the FAT32.

Comment: @fixer1234 Okay.

Answer (score 0):

Open the manager view by double-clicking Ext2Fsd in the start menu.  See if you can see the second partition there.  If so, highlight it and choose one of the mounting options.

Comment: All right, I'll try when I get on my computer.